Disable Dragging of YouTube Transcripts with a Chrome Extension
How can I develop a Chrome extension(javascript) to stop the dragging of YouTube transcripts with the mouse? I want to prevent users from moving the transcript box while allowing other interactions. Could someone point me to the relevant APIs or provide some sample code to achieve this?
i've already asked chagpt but no solution
